# Sort List<T> on a property in a related List<T>

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

Say we have two `List<T>`.  The first is a list of sales totals:

```
class SalesTotals
{
    public Guid EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalSales { get; set; }
}
```

Then we have another list of sales by year:

```
class YearlySales
{
    public Guid EmpID { get; set; }
    public short SalesYear { get; set; }
    public decimal? YearlyTotals { get; set; }
}
```

These are used together to create a "cross tab" report which lists the total sales by each employee, followed by a column for each year with the related yearly sales.  It would look something like this:

```
| Name | Total | 2018 | 2017 | 2016 |
+------+-------+------+------+------+
|  Joe |    70 |   20 |      |   50 |
|  Sam |    60 |   30 |   20 |   10 |
| Fred |    50 |   30 |      |   20 |
|  Bob |    40 |   10 |   15 |   15 |
```

By default, the report is sorted by TotalSales (no problem).  But if we want to sort by an individual year, things get trickier.  Sorted by 2017 (then by total):

```
| Name | Total | 2018 | 2017 | 2016 |
+------+-------+------+------+------+
|  Sam |    60 |   30 |   20 |   10 |
|  Bob |    40 |   10 |   15 |   15 |
|  Joe |    70 |   20 |      |   50 |
| Fred |    50 |   30 |      |   20 |
```

I assume we want to (Left) `Join` these two `List<T>`s on `EmpID`, `where SalesYear == <year to sort by>` then `OrderBy` `YearlyTotals, TotalSales` (since YearlyTotals might not exist for a given year, and we still want some type of order in that case).  So we also have to consider that there might not be a record for that year to join with (so it needs to be a left join).

If I were writing SQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT ST.EmpID, ST.EmpName, ST.TotalSales
FROM SalesTotals AS ST
LEFT JOIN YearlySales AS YS ON ST.EmpID=YS.EmpID
WHERE YS.SalesYear=@SortBySalesYear OR YS.SalesYear IS NULL
ORDER BY YS.YearlySales DESC, ST.TotalSales DESC
```

I'm not good enough with Linq (yet) to be able to figure this out.  In fact, I was able to get virtually no where (maybe trying to do too much at once, perhaps I need to break it down in to individual steps, and not search for the one liner).

So, is there a way to do this with Linq?  Or should I be attempting some other type of approach?

Note: All I need is an "in place" sort here.  I don't need/want a different type of `List<T>` returned here, just a sorted `List<SalesTotals>`.

Edit: I prefer the Linq "Query Syntax" as it is more intuitive to me (strong SQL background).  So I prefer an answer using Query Syntax as opposed to Method Syntax.

Edit: Here is a test case setup:

```
class SalesTotals
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalSales { get; set; }
}
class YearlySales
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public short SalesYear { get; set; }
    public decimal? YearlyTotals { get; set; }
}
class TestSort
{
    public TestSort()
    {
        var st = new List<SalesTotals>
        {
            new SalesTotals() { EmpID = 1, EmpName = "Joe", TotalSales = 70 },
            new SalesTotals() { EmpID = 2, EmpName = "Sam", TotalSales = 60 },
            new SalesTotals() { EmpID = 3, EmpName = "Fred", TotalSales = 50 },
            new SalesTotals() { EmpID = 4, EmpName = "Bob", TotalSales = 40 }
        };

        var ys = new List<YearlySales>
        {
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 1, SalesYear = 2018, YearlyTotals = 20 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 2, SalesYear = 2018, YearlyTotals = 30 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 3, SalesYear = 2018, YearlyTotals = 30 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 4, SalesYear = 2018, YearlyTotals = 10 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 2, SalesYear = 2017, YearlyTotals = 20 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 4, SalesYear = 2017, YearlyTotals = 15 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 1, SalesYear = 2016, YearlyTotals = 10 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 2, SalesYear = 2016, YearlyTotals = 15 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 3, SalesYear = 2016, YearlyTotals = 50 },
            new YearlySales() { EmpID = 4, SalesYear = 2016, YearlyTotals = 20 }
        };

        st = SortByYear(st, ys, 2017);
    }
    private List<SalesTotals> SortByYear(List<SalesTotals> salesTotals, List<YearlySales> yearlySales, short sortYear)
    {
        // return sorted salesTotals by sortYear using both salesTotals and yearlySales joined on EmpID
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of the data in the two lists that you use to generate the given results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Saw that question, and it helps, but it didn't address sorting, and didn't seem picky about return type.

Comment: Requirement to sort in-place contradicts requirement to use LINQ (whether query syntax or not).

Comment: @Evk I am aware of that, but Linq seems to be the easiest to implement at this point.  I was clarifying that I needed "in place" sort here to emphasize that I wanted to "get back" an exact copy of the List<T> sorted, not some other type of List<T>.  This would also open the door for other methods of achieving the goal (without the use of Linq)

Comment: Your second class won't compile because a member name and the class name are the same?

Comment: Yea I just saw that too...  Adding a test case for you that I actually wrote in VS this time =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than convert the SQL directly, I think it is a little clearer to break the query into two parts.

First, find the `YearlySales` for the year to sort by:

```
var sortYearSales = from ys in yearlySales
                    where ys.SalesYear == SortBySalesYear
                    select ys;
```

Then you can left join on that and sort (since `ys` might by `null`, I used the null conditional member acecss operator):

```
var orderedSalesTotals = (from st in salesTotals
                          join ys in sortYearSales on st.EmpID equals ys.EmpID into ysj
                          from ys in ysj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          orderby ys?.YearSales descending, st.TotalSales descending
                          select st).ToList();
```

Note: I changed the name of the `YearlySales` member to `YearSales` since the C# compiler complained about the member and class having the same name.

You can do it in a single query, but you must either nest the first query into the second, or use lambda syntax in the query:

```
var orderedSalesTotals = (from st in salesTotals
                          join ys in yearlySales on st.EmpID equals ys.EmpID into ysj
                          from ys in ysj.Where(y => y.SalesYear == SortBySalesYear).DefaultIfEmpty()
                          orderby ys?.YearSales descending, st.TotalSales descending
                          select st).ToList();
```

Comment: Ka POW!  That knocked it out of the park!  Would have been nice to have it all in one go, but this will do fine.  +1 on the null conditional.  All I did was add in an `ys == null` ahead of the other orderby clause members to get nulls to show up last, and wala.  Thx very much!

Comment: @Scuzzlebutt No problem. I added a single query example but it requires mixing lambda syntax or nesting queries do to do it (to be where, that is what you are doing in SQL).

Answer (score 1):

You can write it pretty much the same way you would in SQL!

```
        var results = from t in totals
            join y in years on t.EmpID equals y.EmpID into groupedTable
                      from p in groupedTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where y == null || y.SalesYear == year
                      orderby y.SalesYear, t.TotalSales descending
                      select t;
```

Quick note: Joins in LINQ are by default inner joins. If you want an outer join, you have to use a DefaultIfEmpty() call.

Comment: I think I'm mostly getting tripped up on the left join part, and returning the correct return type `List<SalesTotals>`.  This looks promising...  Trying on my end...

Comment: I'm going to keep working on it, but right off the bat, the `yearly.SalesYear == null` doesn't work because its a `short` (non nullable) type.  To be clear, YearlySales doesn't always include a record for that year, so if there is no sales data for that year, the record won't exist.

Comment: @Scuzzlebutt whoops, that should say where yearly == null. Fixed.

Comment: Ahh, nice, I get it.  Still working on it...  Compiler doesn't like `into tempTbl` after the `orderby` clause...  (a query body must end with a select or group clause)...  I want to select just the SalesTotals, but I don't think I can do that just yet...  Need to handle DefaultIfEmpty() for the YearlySales...  Getting closer, I'll keep working...

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty rusty at the query syntax and only just stepped in front of a compiler. I'll take a look.

Comment: Recall that `OR` in C# is `||` or `|`.

Comment: That feeling when you accidentally use SQL syntax in C# and then Eric Lippert himself sees it. Oof.

Comment: I caught it right away too, but wasn't going to say anything (I knew what you meant!)

Answer (score -1):

Kind of works.  Need to put in a null for sales

```
List<YearlySale> YearlySales = new List<YearlySale>() { new YearlySale() { EmpID = 1, Sales = 700, Year = 2018 },
                                                        new YearlySale() { EmpID = 1, Sales = 600, Year = 2017 },
                                                        new YearlySale() { EmpID = 1, Sales = 500, Year = 2016 },
                                                        new YearlySale() { EmpID = 2, Sales = 400, Year = 2018 },
                                                        new YearlySale() { EmpID = 2, Sales = null, Year = 2017 },
                                                        new YearlySale() { EmpID = 2, Sales = 300, Year = 2016 }
                                                        };
List<SalesTotal> SalesTotals = new List<SalesTotal>() { new SalesTotal() { EmpID = 1, EmpName = "stan", TotalSales  = 1800 },
                                                        new SalesTotal() { EmpID = 2, EmpName = "sally", TotalSales = 700 }

                                                        };
var q = from s in SalesTotals
        join y18 in YearlySales 
            on s.EmpID equals y18.EmpID
        join y17 in YearlySales
            on s.EmpID equals y17.EmpID
        join y16 in YearlySales
            on s.EmpID equals y16.EmpID
        where y18.Year == 2018
        where y17.Year == 2017
        where y16.Year == 2016
        select new { SalesTotal = s, Year18 = y18 == null ? 0 : y18.Year, YearS18 = y18 == null ? 0 : y18.Sales
                                   , Year17 = y17 == null ? 0 : y17.Year, YearS17 = y17 == null ? 0 : y17.Sales
                                   , Year16 = y16 == null ? 0 : y16.Year, YearS16 = y16 == null ? 0 : y16.Sales
                    };
foreach (var v in q.OrderBy(x => x.SalesTotal.EmpID))
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{v.SalesTotal.EmpID} {v.SalesTotal.EmpName} {v.SalesTotal.TotalSales} {v.YearS18} as y18 {v.YearS17} as y17  {v.YearS16} as y16" );
}
```

Comment: The YearlySales object with `Sales = null` won't exist in the `List<YearlySales>`.  If there is no sales data for that year, there will be no record.  Also, I'm not interested in getting a "cross tab" report back.  I just want the original `List<SalesTotals>` returned, but sorted.  So no need (or desire) to include the `YearlySales` detail in the output.  Was hoping to be able to sort in one swoop, otherwise I'd be up to three "copies" of the List<T> in memory right?  (probably not an issue, I'm at most a few hundred items)

Comment: You can insert a null.  If you did not want a cross presentation then why is that how you formatted the question and asked for "cross tab"?

Comment: I very clearly stated that I wanted a `List<SalesTotals>` returned (in the original question).  I showed what the result of the sort would look like to help clarify what the ultimate goal was.  Even the SQL I wrote included only the SalesTotal fields...